# What are the differences between the two personalities of Seijūrō Akashi?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

In Kuroko no Basket, the captain of Teiko Middle School and Rakuzan High is revealed to have a split personality. His original personality is shown to be that of a team player: likable and helpful to others. In his final year he suppressed this personality during his 1v1 match vs Murasakibara and awakened his special ability, Emperor Eye.

Midorima and Kuroko in particular note the personality changes in Akashi. The most obvious I can find is that the new personality refers to people by their first names i.e. Kuroko as Tetsuya, Midorima as Shintaro.

Are there any other changes between the two personalities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akashi Seijuurou has a split personality, we'll call the first personality "Boku" and the second personality "Ore".

"Boku" is mainly the personality that was shown in the first few Teiko years and also sometime during the Rakuzan-Seirin game. "Ore" was seen after his one-on-one with Murasakibara until the Rakuzan-Seirin game and also a bit in the Vorpal Swords-Jabberwocks game.

"Boku" is generally more caring until Aomine called Akashi "nagging mother". Honestly, I'd say that "Boku" kind of has an inferiority complex because he seems more humble and he admits in Teiko that everyone was becoming better than him. He also admits that he has a weakness of fearing being left behind (as pointed out by Ore during their mental talks). "Ore" on the other hand, has a superiority complex. He says that people should "lower their head" and that he is "absolute" and he is constantly so sure that he will always win. He calls people by their given name which is not really disrespectful or shows signs of superiority or anything but it's just more respectful to use the last names.

Another clear sign (in the anime) is that "Boku"'s eyes are both red while "Ore"'s eyes ahs the right one red and the left one yellow. It's not very noticeable in the manga. "Boku" also focuses a lot on team play while "Ore" focuses more on winning no matter what. This is why "Boku" can do things like perfect-rhythm-plays and gets not only him but his other teammates into the zone as well while "Ore" gets into the zone by abandoning all hope for his teammates.

There are a lot of differences between the two personalities for the plays he makes. Of the two, it is said that "Boku" is stronger. However, both "Boku" and "Ore" were not strong enough to stop Nash and his Belial Eye and to defeat him, "Ore" had to disappear and transfer his abilities to "Boku" in order for the Emperor Eye to be complete. It's rather sad but... yeah.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember (it's been a while since the end of the manga) the most notable difference comes with the special ability that the personalities have:

- The new personality has, as you said, The Emperor's Eye ability, which leads him to easily defeat most of his rivals in 1v1 or sometimes even in 1v2 or 1v3 depending on the "power" of his rivals. Also he acts like a superior being, considering himself way better than others and not caring about training or hard work, but just being interested in powerful teammates and in winning at every cost. Also he calls everyone by his first names.
- The original, on the other side, is very helpful and proning to teamplay. Is because of this that he awakens his "true" special ability, wich is the "Zone" (that a lot of the main characters awaken in the story) but the difference with his zone is the fact that he can help every one of his teammates to enter in the zone without much effort, which makes this a very powerful and dangerous ability. This personality calls people by their last names as a sign of respect.

In the end he is able to combine both of them in order to become even a better basketball player having an enormous defense zone.

Also and just as an interesting detail, the original personality has red eyes, while the "Emperor" one has one eye red and the other gilded.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the personalities is that the original Akashi was more fluent in his passes and most of his shots. You see this in the fight between Seirin and Rakuzan. The personality change was because he didn't want to lose his team, the only people who could understand him. But the change caused the Generation Of Miracles to break. Earlier on in season 3 it's shown that Midorima had noticed these indefinite changes between the original Akashi and The Emperor Akashi. The original Akashi wanted to bring his team closer so he switched to Emperor Eye. But it didn't do anything but push them away.